# "Last edited by" - how to translate?

Tags: translation

I'm struggling to understand how to translate "Last Edited By", for an online document.

I think there must be another english phrase to use, and translate that, but I just cannot think what it could be.

先の編集者 (previous editor)  ?

and subsequently the "Last Edited Date"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most natural translation (though not literal) would be 最終編集者 and 最終編集日／最終編集日時. You can also use 更新者 (updater) instead.

> 最終更新者: naruto
>   最終更新日時: 2015年5月21日 15:05

先の (=prior) would not work as you expect in this case.

Comment: This expression is exactly what I need, thank you.